# Ubuntu 16.04 -ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run this line of code

$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64,i386,ppc64el] http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.5/ubuntu xenial main'

I am getting an error-

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 12, in 
from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in 
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

I have tried multiple solutions , nothing seems to work

Comment: Did you tried to follow solutions explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069087/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-error ?

Comment: yes i tried , but didnt work